# How can we calculate the combined stiffness of a spline connected to a straight member?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, mathematics

I have a geometry that looks something like this. What will be the combined stiffness of the members?

[image: Figure indicating the geometry]

Comment: Which stiffness? Axial? Bending? The full stiffness matrix? Considering p-\delta effects or in the linear regime?

Comment: This is basically a slice from cochlea, where the bending part(material 2) is basilar membrane and the material 1, is a bridge tissue. both of them bend but their individual stiffness is different. For our model we are assuming them to be isotropic. I am primarily interested in the bending stiffness.

Comment: I get that the materials are different, but what are your expected loads? Are they point loads or distributed loads? What's the loading direction? Are you expecting large deformations?

Comment: Load is distributed and given by p = p0*sin(wt) and acting along the length of the slice i.e. from the bottom in the current view.

Answer (score 0):

Each part stiffness is the $EI$ of that part.

However, calculating the deflection under a certain load analytically by hand could be a term project.

## Edit

I searched for assembling the global stiffness matrix from member local stiffness matrices.
Here is a couple of answers.

[global 2](https://extension://pjmlamaidnkoemaaofddboidllnogmhe/https://community.ptc.com/sejnu66972/attachments/sejnu66972/PTCMathcad/179515/1/BeamStiffness.pdf)

[golbal link](https://extension://pjmlamaidnkoemaaofddboidllnogmhe/https://www.sjsu.edu/people/steven.vukazich/docs/160%20Beam%20Direct%20Stiff%20Lab%2011.pdf)

Comment: I am using Comsol for simulations but currently I am using the series approximation for the stiffness but my results are way off than the experimentally reported results for deflection values. Currently I am using single value of stiffness for each member. Can you please elaborate how we can get a good formulation for the stiffness matrix?

Comment: I added two links to my answer. Take a look.